# How to search C5.TreeSet?

Tags: .net, c5

I have a `C5.TreeSet<double>`, a sorted data structure. https://github.com/sestoft/C5/

Given a value `x`, I'd like to search the set `S` for the greatest index `i` such `S[j] <= x` for all j ≤ i (similar to Python's `bisect.bisect`). How can I do that?

I was previously using `List<T>` with [`BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When S is a TreeSet, or more generally, an IIndexedSorted, then S.CountTo(x) will give you the number of items strictly less than x.

Comment: Is there a version with non-strict inequality?